# How to set msipackage installation scope as perUser in a bundle in wix?

Tags: bundle, wix4

Using Wix4, I have two dual-purpose msi package in a bundle, my question is how to set package scope to perUser in bundle? Package group like this:

I built the bundle and tried to run it. but it required elevation.
That is not I want, because for a dual-purpose package, if I don't
set allusers property, default installation should be per-User rather than per-Machine.